# Can an ADXL327 accelerometer be used with theoretically unlimited bandwidth?

Tags: accelerometer, bandwidth, frequency-response, cutoff-frequency

I saw several studies that use the 3-axis ADXL327 accelerometer, 0.1-3000 Hz band-pass filtered and sampled at 20KHz based on previous studies that showed that the signals of interest have frequencies in that range.

The [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL327.pdf) of the ADXL327 says that the bandwidth can be set from 0.5 to 1600 Hz in X, Y axis and 0 to 500 Hz in Z axis. Is there something I missed (most likely) or do these studies make a wrong assumption?

Comment: To my knowledge unlimited bandwidth does not exist. Maybe you might elaborate on your question so I can better understand what you are asking?

Comment: Obviously it does not exist. I meant can it expend beyond what is stated or is there a physical limit at the given values ?! The manufacturer gives values which ensure that, in that range, the behavior is tested/guaranted. But can I still get relevant signal beyond those values, with maybe some unexpected behavior ?! I guess that scott seidman gave a relevant answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expect to have a frequency response for half power BW greater than what was stated. Lesser powers at high frequency will pass with the filter slope and the accelerometer has a resonant frequency near 5kHz which must be avoided.

The sampling rate must be at least 3x greater than the selected BW to prevent aliasing.  If you need to record greater bandwidths , then this is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

From the data sheet:

| FREQUENCY RESPONSE |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bandwidth | XOUT, YOUT No external filter | 1600 Hz |
| Bandwidth | ZOUT No external filter | 550 Hz |
| RFILT Tolerance |  | 32 ± 15% kΩ |
| Sensor Resonant Frequency |  | 5.5 kHz |

It's unclear to me whether the limits are due to internal filtering on their output amps or some mechanical characteristic of the nanomaterial used

In any case, this doesn't guarantee that higher frequency signals can't come out of the device -- you just don't know if they're attenuated, or amplified by the resonance of the crystal.  They may be there, but you can't trust them.

The data presented in the papers you mention is therefore suspect, unless the authors somehow did careful spectral calibrations.